# Who am I? - Riddle

Tags: riddle

> I am you, you are me.
>
> I see you and you see me.
>
> I friend I am, a enemy too.
>
> Slayer of gods, murdered me too.
>
> I kill you now, hunt you never.
>
> Clash with your head, kill your tether.

Who am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This one was pretty hard but here we go (my opinion)

> I think you are our consciousness

```
I am you, you are me.
I see you and you see me.
I friend I am, a enemy too.
```

> We are our consciousness. When we think about ourselves, we don't think about our body, we think about our consciousness, our personality, the things we like etc.. And sometimes our consciousness can be an enemy because it may take us to do bad things, but also good things!

```
Slayer of gods, murdered me too.
I kill you now, hunt you never.
```

> Our consciousness, sometimes, make us think we are the best ("Slayer of gods"), and sometimes make us think we are completely useless in the world, that no one likes us("murdered me too")..

```
Clash with your head, kill your tether.
```

> A "Clash" with our head, can kill some cells, and the blood "tether" will not flow, what brings consciousness again because it "kills" some parts of ourselves, of our consciousness

Tried my best! Wanna see others opinions